# How to zip and ignore all files specified by .gitignore

Tags: bash, git, command-line

I have a few dozen git repositories under one directory, all of them contain not only source code but also build artifact, developer artifact, blobs and other data normally ignored by .gitignore

I would like to quickly transfer these source code to another computer. Is there an easy way to package everything that is not ignored by git?

To add more context:

I have 50-ish git folders or so, each on different branches with some current changes

I would like to copy all files that are tracked by git, at the current state ( current branch plus current local change )

If by cloning them all, it means to go to each folder, commit the current changes locally, remember the branch name, git clone local branch to another folder, do that 50 times then I am strongly agaist it

Comment: Source code without history? https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive

Comment: Why not just clone them all?

Comment: Can I use these commands at upper level, outside all the git trees? 
I have a few dozens of them under one folder which is troublesome to run a command in each git folder

Comment: You mention concerns about artifacts which are not versioned, it it a problem if they get copied over ? If not : copy / pasting the base folder or creating a `.tgz` from it also work.

Comment: @StephenNewell I added more context into the question,

Answer (score 10):

One-liner:

```
$ alias gitzip="git archive HEAD -o ${PWD##*/}.zip"
$ cd mydir
$ gitzip
```

Comment: This unfortunately only zips committed files, not unstaged changes

Comment: It also zips the .gitignore file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to include history, use [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) (or [`xeyownt/git-subundle`](https://github.com/xeyownt/git-subundle) if your repositories have submodules)

See [this script](https://gist.github.com/robatwilliams/ea326929efeeae0f914869402a4874b0) as an example:

```sh
for repository in ${repositories[@]}
do
  echo "$repository..."
  declare file_name="../$repository-$(git rev-parse --short HEAD).bundle"
  cd $repository
  if [ -f $file_name ]; then
    echo 'Found bundle is current'
  else
    git bundle create $file_name --all
  fi
  cd -
done
```

Each repository gives one file (without anyprivate or ignored files), that you can easily copy and, once copied, cloned from.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this :

```
for dir in repo1 repo2 repo3; do
    git -C "$dir" ls-files | perl -pe "s[^][$dir/]"
done | zip /tmp/test.zip -@
```